# How to put a POST response in a tab of String?

Tags: java, android, string, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 and I am getting a POST response in a format stated bellow. I am trying to put every line in its own tab bracket.

This is a response format:

aaaa

bb

cc

dd

I am trying to make it like this:

```
String[] tab = {"aaaa", "bb", "cc", "dd"};
```

This is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){ //ce prekinemo skeniranje
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scann canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            ...//here I want to put response into my tab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line of code you are looking for!

```
String[] tab = result.getContents().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```